# Cannot install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 3 - “watchdog: BUG: soft lockup: - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [migration/1:15]”

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, acer-aspire

I am trying to install Ubuntu Mate on my Acer Aspire 3, with AMD Ryzen 3 2200U and AMD Radeon Vega 3 Graphics, currently running Windows 10. When I boot from a USB and select "Install Ubuntu Mate" I am getting the following error:[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZ4a.jpg)

After that I disabled AMD-SVM and AMD-IOMMU in the BIOS menu, which cleared the first several lines of errors, but I still get some errors and cannot install Ubuntu:[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eeme.jpg)

Can anyone help me out with this annoying issue? I contacted the Acer support as well, but they said they cannot help since this is regarding a different OS than Windows.